# Mensaje de error: "io.UnsupportedOperation: not readable" en Python

Tags: python, python-3.x

Quiero hacer un programita que lea un archivo txt y genere un lista de líneas de dicho archivo.
El código que tengo es el siguiente:

```
f = open("rutas de archivos.txt","w",encoding="utf8")
linesfilelist = f.readlines()
f.close()
```

Al ejecutar este programa me sale el siguiente mensaje de error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "C:\...", line 2, in <module>
linesfilelist = f.readlines()
io.UnsupportedOperation: not readable
```

¿Qué significa?

Comment: Significa que la ruta que le das al método open es incorrecto, o que el programa no tiene permiso para accesarlo

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Es porque te estás equivocando en como usar el archivo, en lugar de 'w' (write) usa 'r' (read)

```
f = open("rutas de archivos.txt","r",encoding="utf8")
linesfilelist = f.readlines()
f.close()
```

así ya funciona.